# How can i push a view onto a sheet? SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have page that you click a button, bottom sheet pop ups, you click another button and the expected result is the view pushes over it, however i am unsure of how to push a view over

```
 Text("Add")
                                                .padding(.horizontal, 5)
                                                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                                                .font(.custom("CashMarket-Medium", size: 17))
                                                .frame(width: 300, height: 10, alignment: .center)
                                            
                                            
                                        }.buttonStyle(AddCashbutton())
```

this code is inside of a bottom sheet, and when you click this button i want a view

```
LoadingView()
```

to appear over the sheet

If anyone can help me thank you!

Comment: Show a minimal code with the `Button` and the bottom `sheet` and enough context to
 understand what you are trying to do, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
  Are you trying to display a `sheet` on top of another `sheet`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.sheet` modifier. Here is the code:

```
struct mainPage: View{
    @State private var isAdding = false
    var body: some View{
        NavigationStack{
            Button("Add"){ isAdding.toggle() }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isAdding){
             LoadingView()
        }
    }
}
```